# Problems passing JavaScript variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having problems passing a variable from my JS function to another PHP file on using submit button.
I have a booking form, it calculates the total amount using JS, I want to send this total to another page called "payment.php", i am using the following code, but nothing updates on the cart when it redirects to payment.php
I want this to be done when the user has done selecting the stuff, he then presses the checkout button, on which this should be sent but it aint working.
Help required

Here is the JS code:

```
function payment(){
    var totalPrice = calTotal();
    document.getElementById("total").value= totalPrice;
    window.location.href = "payment.php?total=" + totalPrice; 
}
```

calTotal() is another function which is doing calulations, its working perfectly.

Here is the code on my receiving PHP page:

```
<?php
$total = $_GET['total'];
echo $total;
?>
```

I am actually trying to make a school form, there is just one form and it is on a php page,  the user selects checkbboxes, for this I used JS, as the user checks it adds up to total using calTotal() on client-side, and displays it using .innerHTML function. What I want to happen is that, I want this variable to be sent over to another php page, say payment.php . I want this variable to appear as it on my payment page as well, but its not fetching the variable, I tried some methods I knew and also tried the suggestions given by @cocco, but all in vain.. Need help.

Comment: `calTable() works perfectly`... so you can `console.log(totalPrice)` before you redirect away (return false after console.log to stop that) and your console shows the correct value?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  Can you post the HTML?

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question but: You're calculating the price in the browser, instead of the server? That seems a bit dubious, security-wise, although I can't say for sure without seeing the full thing. Presumably you'll have other parameters to say what is being ordered. So a malicious user could send a request saying "Please send me 1000 items, and charge my account $0.50"

Comment: calTotal isn't completing and the browser is forwarding you. Instead of location.href, add `alert(totalPrice);` to see it's working. You can even leave the 3rd line and you'll see that it does pass the value with an alert before it

Comment: are you trying to send the total amount to 2 different php pages?

Comment: @DavidKnipe I understand the risks, but I am not using it order courses, I am making a schooling site, so the function is calculating the total of the courses seleceted by the user (using JS - client side) and want this exact amount to be able to be received by my php payment page, so I can mail to them the total amount of their selected courses without recalculating again on the php page.. Hope this clears my requirements a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Working code:**

js

```
YOURPAYMENTFORM.onsubmit=function(e){
 this.total.value=calTotal();
 this.submit();
 return false
}
// if you have only one form you can access it by document.forms[0]
// and so have document.forms[0].onsubmit=function(e){..
```

php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['total'];
?>
```

---

**What is wrong:**

You are trying to `post`(onsubmit) to a page and at the same time you try to reach another page with `get`(window.location).

why?

when you have a submit button inside a form it try's to send the whole form to the specified site in the form element but you need want to calculate the total price first.

even if you stop that (return false), an user could click enter and it does the same.

thats why i added the function(payment) directly to the form element.

---

------------------------Problem 1

if `document.getElementById("total").value= totalPrice;` is inside your form
and your payment page is `payment.php` you just can call `$_POST['total']` inside your receiving PHP

```
<?php
$total = $_POST['total'];
echo $total;
?>
```

**but before you do that you need to calculate the total amount with another button.**

------------------------Problem 2

By adding onsubmit on your payment form element you have total control over it

with `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` you can stop it from sending the information
and go to the `"payment.php?total=" + totalPrice;` page.

```
YOURPAYMENTFORM.onsubmit=function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var totalPrice = calTotal();
 document.getElementById("total").value= totalPrice;
 window.location.href = "payment.php?total=" + totalPrice;
 return false
}
```

**but in this case you don't send any post variables.**

Comment: This isn't what he's trying to do. He's not posting a form

Comment: i'm just explaining what the errors are inside his code..read after 'SO to put everything together'

Comment: onsubmit is the perfect way to post a form as it's executed if you press enter inside a form or if you click the assigned submit button.

Comment: Yes his method would be a disaster on a live web site but there's a reason his code doesn't work when it should. I think that should be answered first followed by an important note to say his method is terrible if it's used for a live site

Comment: @cocco i tried what you said but still I receive nothing on my PHP page. :(

Comment: $_POST['total'] -- not $_GET['total']... and is the total input inside the form? maybe if you post some more code it's easier for us to understand the problem ..

Answer (score 0):

If `payment` is an event handler for submitting the form, then you will probably need to call `preventDefault()` on your Event object in order to keep the browser from submitting the form and basically overriding your redirect.  Alternatively, you could have a hidden field in the form that submits the calculated total, and set that on submit, and it'd be posted along with whatever else is in the form.

For reference, though, either of those is rather ugly from a progressive-enhancement point of view.  You are basically *requiring* that people have JS enabled in order for stuff to not look broken.  This stuff is more correctly handled server-side.  (Particularly if you use that value for anything important!  You're basically letting the client decide how much your stuff costs.  Don't trust it; do your own calculations on the server.)